# Location redirect all /*.xml to /*

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to redirect all /filename.xml files to /filename.

I can redirect an individual file like this

```
location = /mascus-export.xml {
     rewrite .* /mascus-export redirect;
}
```

but rather than listing each .xml file like individually, I want redirect all. Something like this:

```
location = /*.xml {
     rewrite .* /* redirect;
}
```

I've tried this type of thing in every combination

```
location = /(*)$.xml {
     rewrite .* /$1 redirect;
}
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write a *regular expression* `location` block, which begins with `~` and not `=`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ \.xml$ { ... }
```

The `rewrite` needs to capture part of the URI using parentheses. For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\.xml$ $1 redirect;
```

The `rewrite` will work perfectly well either enclosed within the above `location` block, or just naked within the enclosing `server` block.

---

If you are going to use a regular expression `location` block, you do not need to use a `rewrite` statement too. Use a `return` statement instead. For example:

```
location ~ ^(.*)\.xml$ { 
    return 302 $1;
}
```

Comment: Both solutions within the location box failed, but the naked rewrite line works. Gets us around a very weird server problem we have. Thanks.

Comment: I should have mentioned that regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order. Maybe there is a conflicting location before the one you are inserting. But the naked rewrite should be just as efficient and is evaluated earlier so is less susceptible to conflicts.